# Command line build task to run an exe

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm looking at migrating our work from an in-house TFS server to VSTS. I've been testing VSTS build definitions as we use a few custom tasks, including one that runs a batch file which in turn runs [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to generate a "setup.exe" file.

Can this be achieved using the "command line" build task? I realise we can't install our own software on a hosted agent, but could I run the InnoSetup exe if it was under source control (i.e. present in the "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"), or are there restrictions to prevent exes from being run on the VSTS build server?

Assuming this *is* possible, the batch file requires an argument - the path to where the setup.exe will be created. What would I use here?

I have tried to simulate what I'm looking to do using a batch file that generates a text file from a "dir" command (using the argument as the path):

```
dir *.* >%1\test.txt
```

I used `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` as the command line task's argument, but there was no "test.txt" file in the artifacts. I guess it's not that simple! (The batch file *did* run, as the build output showed some "echo" commands that I had included).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I realised I needed to put my command line task before the "publish artifact" task. I guess the latter is responsible for bundling everything up in the artifact staging directory.

Next I need to add the InnoSetup exe to source control and see if I can run that from the command line task, but it's a step in the right direction...